# Is it correct that search on AskUbuntu ignores code blocks and inline codes?

Tags: support, search, code

Sometimes I want to search posts which mention `some-command-name` by using

```
`some-command-name`
```

formatting or maybe also multi-line code blocks (`<pre>`, `<code>` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

As of today the search query for the [quoted term `"mate-disk-usage-analyzer"` is failed](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22mate-disk-usage-analyzer%22):

> [image: search for quoted "mate-disk-usage-analyzer" failed]

but is shows the result if [I remove the quotes](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mate-disk-usage-analyzer):

> [image: search for mate-disk-usage-analyzer]

and what is interesting the requested term `mate-disk-usage-analyzer` is not highglighted/bolded in the search result.

But I know that for example my post from search results contains requested code block (see [A: How do I find the amount of free space on my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051417/66509) and [its source](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/01be51cc-3cb2-487c-941c-17812fb78dcc/view-source)):

> [image: source code of my answer with search term]

I expect that users can find posts by their contents of inline code and code blocks.

Is it correct that search on AskUbuntu ignores code blocks and inline codes?

Comment: I would call it a bug!

Comment: Hey @N0rbert, drop by [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) sometime!  **;-) +1**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's [a special syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132632/270345) for searching in code blocks. Search for `code:"mate-disk-usage-analyzer"` and your answer is the only hit:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Works as expected. I'll remember this hint :)

Comment: Couldn't that be added to https://askubuntu.com/help/searching ?