# What is required to become a moderator?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, badges, moderators

I can see some moderators editing posts here...
These moderators have little reputation points such as 100 approx. and few silver and bronze badges.

I wish to know what it takes to be a moderator on Ask Ubuntu or the Meta site.

Thanks.

Comment: Any individual with 2000+ reputation can make edits freely, though if they abuse that it gets oversight from those of us who are elected moderators (we have diamonds next to our name!).  Any individual can *propose* edits, however, for community review by those with edit privileges.  Moderators can edit freely as can SE Employees (though we're bound by the same rules and regulations for contribution, and the SE Employees govern the conduct of the elected moderators)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're talking about these two recent posts:

- [2 year old user is a new contributor?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18279/2-year-old-user-is-a-new-contributor)
- [Is it correct that search on AskUbuntu ignores code blocks and inline codes?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18276/is-it-correct-that-search-on-askubuntu-ignores-code-blocks-and-inline-codes)

These were edited by [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) and [Adam Lear](https://stackexchange.com/users/37099/adam-lear). These two guys are Stack Exchange employees, so they have network-wide phenomenal cosmic powers and mod diamonds everywhere they go. They don't have much rep on Ask Ubuntu, since they haven't used this site much. However, they have lots of rep on other sites in the network. They became employees after contributing outstandingly to other Stack Exchange sites.

SE employees tend to drop by when any site's child meta gets a question tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) since if there really is a bug they'll have to fix it, and if a feature request is to be implemented, they'll have to implement it. They often edit the tags on those posts to indicate the status of the report/request, though site mods also handle many such posts if there's no need for attention from employees. Only moderators can add the red <kbd>status</kbd> tags. You're also likely to see employees around when there is a moderator election.

The election of moderators is explained in [this page of our Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/site-moderators). On new SE sites, mods are appointed by SE employees, but on mature sites, they are always elected by popular vote.

A humble ordinary moderator(!) rather than a Stack Exchange employee will in general have a lot of reputation and badges and suchlike on the site where they are a mod, since many members of the voting community are likely to interpret these as a measure of a user's contributions and commitment to the site. All our [Ask Ubuntu moderators](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) have many reputation points and badges.

A moderator on a site like Ask Ubuntu is also a moderator on that site's child meta, as you'd probably expect. There's no way to become a moderator only of a child meta.

Comment: [Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/468333)

Answer (score 4):

What you're referring to is probably editors and it takes 2000 rep to become an editor.

*On the main site,* if the user is a few 100 rep, he's just a user that has to go through a review process before his/her edits are approved.

*On Meta,* only 2000 rep users can edit as per Zanna in the comments.

For all privileges and the rep they need look [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges)

I'm not a moderator: moderators have a diamond next to their name like

- [this one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth)
- [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward)
- [here as well](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon)

What it takes to become a mod is: *Being elected.*

There are also <s>rep whores</s> very high rep users like [this one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) that just want to be a user and *do not want to be a mod*.

Comment: I don''t think there is a mechanism to suggest edits on child meta sites - only users with 2k (and mods) can edit here, unless the post is a community wiki

Comment: I bow to the wisdom of @Zanna **;-) :-)** (edited)

Comment: Ok. I have understood a lot from your answer, but even though the moderators are elected, users will definitely elect with criteria... I mean like based on their interpretation, say high reputation points and badges.

Comment: Not necessarily:  my preference is for them to be easy-going, have a sense of humour and have all the moderator badges... @YufenyuyVeyehDider

Comment: Hahaha! That's quite True.
Just an aside: I have accepted Zanna's answer, and like you said; I bow to the wisdom of @Zanna... :)

Comment: I've just upvoted her answer! @YufenyuyVeyehDider

Comment: What?! Big LOL... Zanna, I didn't know was a lady. Never took a look at her profile. I just did.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask who can do direct edits, everyone with more than 2000 reputation.

Remember: AskUbuntu and any other Stackexchange site is moderated by its users mostly.

When it comes to be a moderator they are getting elected if there is need for expanding the moderator base.